# How to use instance methods in python meta programming?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, metaclass

I have a class `A`:

```
class A(object):
  a = 'a'
  def __init__(self):
    self.b = 'b'
  def foo(self):
    print A.a
    print self.b
```

I just wondering how to construct this class by meta programming.

I have tried:

```
def Init(self):
  self.b = 'b' 

def Foo(self):
  print A_CLASS.a
  print self.b

A_CLASS = type('A_CLASS',(object,),{'a':'a','__init__':Init,'foo':Foo})

myObj = A_CLASS()
myObj.foo()
```

It's works, but still have some problem, that is， I have to use `A_CLASS` as the name of the class, if I use `B_CLASS`, it doesn't work anymore:

```
B_CLASS = type('A_CLASS',(object,),{'a':'a','__init__':Init,'foo':Foo})

myObj = B_CLASS()
myObj.foo() #Error ocurred
```

If there is a way to construct such a class, where the name of the variable 'X_CLASS' is not relevant at all?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs because `Foo` unconditionally references `A_CLASS`, but you bound the class to a global name `B_CLASS`. This is going to be a problem in other circumstances (`pickle` relies on the class name matching the name it was bound to in the defining module), but for this limited case it's fixable. Instead of referring to `A_CLASS.a` directly, refer to it in terms of `self`:

```
def Foo(self):
  print self.a
  print self.b
```

`self` will look for class attributes if no instance attribute of that name exists. If you want to be 100% sure it came from the class, not the instance, you can instead define it as:

```
def Foo(self):
  # New-style class only, but safe against weirdness like redefining __class__
  print type(self).a
  # Old-style class, and vast majority of non-pathological new-style classes
  print self.__class__.a

  print self.b
```

which looks up the class, then gets the attribute from the class, bypassing instance attributes.

In an inheritance hierarchy, this might be wrong. If there is a `A_CHILD` class with a different `a` class attribute, calling `Foo` on it will get the child's attribute. But that's the price of violating the rules; if you give a class the name `A_CLASS` and bind it to the name `B_CLASS`, you can't refer to it by the name `A_CLASS` for lookup (because there is no part of your program that has that binding).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use the name `A_CLASS` literally in `Foo`. You can always get the runtime class of the current object with `self.__class__`.

```
def Foo(self):
  print self.__class__.a
  print self.b
```